# Is there a way to test if a code don't have any issues without actually running it?

Tags: code-review

I have a code that is too much for my computer to hold. This code will be computed later in a powerful system. Is there a way to verify if there is some syntax error or another issue with the code without running it?

Comment: I use WorkBench. It will check syntax errors and other things also. Frontend also checks syntax errors using different coloring. But I think workbench is better at this.

Comment: @Nasser I can run at least the beginning of it, and it seems to be okay. I'll take a look at WorkBench. Thanks for the tip. :-)